# Probability that construction fails

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have the following problem:

> The resistance D has a normal distribution with expectation 11 and
> variance = 2. The force B has a normal distribution with expectation 9
> and variance 1. Assume independence. What is the probability that the
> construction doesn't fail.

The answer is 0.8749

What I did already is draw the two normal distributions. I know that the construction will fail if the force is bigger than the resistance. So I have two intersecting normal distributions and I drew a vertical line through the intersection. Right of the line is the region where the resistance is bigger than the force.

But how do I calculate this region?

Comment: Perhaps make a new variable $Z = D- B$ ?  And then we're interested in the distribution of $Z$ and, in particular, if $Z>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random variable

$Y=(D-B)\sim N(2;3)$

so you can easily calculate

$\mathbb{P}[Y>0]=1-\Phi(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{3}})=1-\Phi(-1.15) \approx 87.49\%$